# How to show custom validation message for username input?

Tags: android, validation, input

I am trying to validate username input when creating new account.

I have these constrains:

```
^(?=.{3,14}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$
```

`^(?=.{3,14}$)`   for username is 3-14 characters long

`(?![_.])`    username can`t start with . or _

`(?!.*[_.]{2})`  no __ or *. or .* or .. inside username

`[a-zA-Z0-9._]`  allowed characters

`(?<![_.])$` username can not end with

and other error messages also.

This is my method (Note that i use TextInputEditText object)

```
private boolean isUsernameValidated() {
    String newUsername =    et_Signup_username.getText().toString().trim();

    if (newUsername.isEmpty()) {
        etLayout_Signup_username.setError("Field can't be empty.");
        return false;
    }   else {
        etLayout_Signup_username.setError(null);
        return true;
    }

}
```

How can I show custom error message like if the username start with `_` or `.` message popup `Username cant start with _ or .` 
 or other error message as shown above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got your issue. Basically, you are trying to show different error messages for different type of errors .

Instead of writing all the long codes, you can use a simple library known as "AwesomeValidation". And you can simply put the following line of code, to make the library validate everything for you.

```
mAwesomeValidation.addValidation(activity, R.id.et_Signup_username, "(?![_.])", R.string.err_name);
```

You can import it by pasting this in your gradle

`implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.2'`

For more details about this library, please check this [link](https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation).

Comment: I`v tried this.  I can register the username and error not recognize

Comment: @andr111 I have updated my answer. So, please try the second method as well. It should work for sure.

Comment: Thank  you, second method is working, but first method for some reason not working.

Comment: @andr111 Glad to hear that. I have updated my answer according to your response. You can now verify the answer as correct.